# How to apply random colors to each letter rather than a word?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, object, dom-events

Example of result:

[image]

It is applying to the whole word. How to apply random color to the each letter?

```js
let input = document.querySelector('.input');
let output = document.querySelector('.output');
let colors = ['tomato', 'deeppink', 'skyblue', 'dodgerblue', 'violet', 'darkslateblue', 'green', 'crimson']


function colorNames(e) {
  let inputVal = document.querySelector('input').value;
  output.innerHTML = inputVal; // print out

  let randomColors = Math.floor((Math.random() * colors.length + 1)); // random color names

  if (output.innerHTML) {
    output.style.color = colors[randomColors];
  }

}

input.addEventListener('input', colorNames);
```

```html
<input type="text" class="input" placeholder="Type your name">

<div class="output">
  <!-- typed value will be printed here -->
</div>
```

Comment: What did you try so far?

Answer (score 0):

```js
var colors = ['tomato', 'deeppink', 'skyblue', 'dodgerblue', 'violet', 'darkslateblue', 'green', 'crimson']
var output = document.querySelector(".output");

var input = document.querySelector(".input");

input.addEventListener("keyup",outputText);

function getRandomColor() {
  return colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
}

function outputText() {
  var val = input.value;
  var res = [];

  for(var i = 0; i < val.length; i++) {
    res[i] = val[i];
    res[i] = '<span style="color:' + getRandomColor() + ';">' + res[i] + '</span>'
  }

  output.innerHTML = "";
  for(var i = 0; i < val.length; i++) {
    output.innerHTML += res[i]
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="input" placeholder="Type your name">

<div class="output">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To set random color to each letter you have to convert each letter as separate element.

You can `split()` all the character with empty string. Then use `map()` to wrap each letter with `span` element so that you can apply style (random color) on each letter. After generating the array you have to `join()` them before assigning to the `innerHTML` property of the output element.

Try the following way:

```js
let input = document.querySelector('.input');
let output = document.querySelector('.output');
let colors = ['tomato', 'deeppink', 'skyblue', 'dodgerblue', 'violet', 'darkslateblue', 'green', 'crimson']


function colorNames(e) {
  let inputVal = document.querySelector('input').value.split('');
  inputVal = inputVal.map(l => {
    let randomColors = Math.floor((Math.random() * colors.length + 1));
    l = '<span style=color:'+colors[randomColors]+'>' + l +'</span>';
    return l;
  });
  output.innerHTML = inputVal.join(''); // print out

}

input.addEventListener('input', colorNames);
```

```html
<input type="text" class="input" placeholder="Type your name">

<div class="output">
   <!-- typed value will be printed here -->
</div>
```